# How to properly add a new interface to bond0?

Tags: networking, sles

After adding a new "interface" to the /etc/sysconfig/ifcfg-foobar:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='1.2.3.4/24'
MTU='9000'
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
USERCONTROL='no'
VLAN_ID='50'
ETHERDEVICE='bond0'
```

What is the proper method to bring this new interface up?

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

just killed my SSH session and had to reboot the server. Came in via another interface that was using bond0. Or the problem was that I wasn't running the /etc/init.d/networking restart command in a screen/tmux session on the server?

Using SLES 11.4

Answer (score 2):

Restart networking is not good idea. You can lose your remote control.

Use `ifenslave` tool to add slaves to master bond0. Don't forget to load bonding module.

```
$ modprobe bonding
```